# app.post on parse heroku server is unauthorized

Tags: http, heroku, parse-platform, twilio, parse-server

I am trying to post to my server from twilio, but I am getting a 403 error. Basically my parse-heroku serve is rejecting any request from twilio. I am working with TWIMLAPP and masked numbers. I am having trouble posting to a function in my index file when a text goes through. In my TWIMLAPP my message url is https://parseserver.herokuapp.com/parse/index/sms Any help is appreciated. These are the errors in twilio [image: Twilio error 1][image: Twilio error 2]

```
var app = express();
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.twilio.com');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

res.setHeader("X-Parse-Master-Key", "xxxxxxx");

res.setHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxxxxx");



// Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});

app.post('/sms', twilio.webhook({ validate: false }), function (req, res) {
  console.log("use-sms")
  from = req.body.From;
  to   = req.body.To;
  body = req.body.Body;

  gatherOutgoingNumber(from, to)
  .then(function (outgoingPhoneNumber) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
twiml.message(body, { to: outgoingPhoneNumber });

res.type('text/xml');
res.send(twiml.toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: I just made a POST request to your URL using curl and received the Heroku "welcome to your new app" page. Your code has a bunch of CORS headers that aren't relevant to webhooks too.

Comment: parseserver is not the actual server url, I used that as a place holder. Also I think the CORS headers are relevant no? when I check the headers in the twilio logs I see my Parse master key and application id. Any reason why I get the unauthorized error

Comment: Well, CORS is for cross origin resource sharing in the browser context. When a server makes an HTTP request to your server it is not held to the same restrictions. As for seeing your Parse keys in the headers, what do you mean exactly? Are you setting those as part of the URL in Twilio?

Comment: The link in twilio is just my server url plus the `/parse/index/sms` path

Comment: Ok, so why are your parse master key and app id in the headers in the logs?

Comment: I added them because after reading a lot of forums, I came to the conclusion that I needed to add those keys as headers to the text message post request. But I dont think that is the case. I am very lost on how to fix the 403 error.

Comment: I add the headers in my server before the failed post request is made